# How to show a loader image in the mean time of the image get retrieved from the server?

Tags: php, mysql, image, loading

I have a product gallery in which the product images will be retreived from the server and shown. It takes sometime for all the images to be retrieved and displayed. I want to show a loading image until the image is rendered from the server.

I have tried as below, by giving an if condition to display a loading image until the image tag gets its source. But its not working, as it just shows a blank space until the image get retrieved from the server.

```
if($image)
    {?>
    <img  style='Max-width:180px;'  alt="Nike Women Sweet Classic High Purple Casual Shoes" src="<?echo $image;?>"><?
    }
    else
    {?>
<img  style='Max-width:180px;'  alt="Nike Women Sweet Classic High Purple Casual Shoes" src="media/images/snake.gif">
<?
}
```

Please tell me how can i make it work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that on the server side alone. One would need to first load simple "snake" images on the php side:

```
<img  style='Max-width:180px;'  alt="Nike Women Sweet Classic High Purple Casual Shoes" src="media/images/snake.gif">
```

and then through javascript (ajax requets) update all the images like so:

```
// populate imageList
$.ajax({
   url: 'your_server_script',
   data: imageList,
   success: function(response) {
      // update teh src property for the images here usign your server response
   }
})
```

As @ranksrejoined pointed out, however, you might be better off using css to give images a container with widht/height and background image. Then that one gets overridden by the image itself.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'd have to use JavaScript to update the DOM as you'd like to, as PHP will only process the page once. Doing so would mean switching to AJAX to retrieve the images, though, and that feels a bit like overkill for your scenario. Instead, why not give each image its own container, and then give that container a class with a loading image as its background? Then. once the image has loaded, it displays over the previous loader.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're suggesting an asynchronous load of the image - you may want to use JavaScript for that.  Something you may like to try as alternative, is to apply a background image to a container for each child image.

```
<div style="background-image: ;">
    <img />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `lowsrc` is deprecated, my best next choice would be Lazy Loading.

That means you only load images that can be seen on the screen right now, and not the images that the browser chooses to load, which can be down the page.

If you use JQuery, then take a look at the nice [LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin. Definitely going forwards this time :)

#### Suggested implementation

you would load the jquery plugin, and write your images like this :

`<img data-original="<?php echo $image; ?>" src="media/images/snake.gif">`

and let the plugin do the hard work

Hope it helps !